# Riesz representation theorem, sinc functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

There is an intimate connection between analytic functions and the completeness of sets of complex exponentials $\{e^{i\lambda_n t}\}$. If, for example, the set $\{e^{i\lambda_n t}\}$ fails to be complete in $C[a,b ]$, then by virtue of the Riesz representation theorem, there is a function $\omega(t)$ of bounded variation on the interval $[a, b]$ that is not essentially a constant and for which
$$\int_a^b e^{i\lambda_n t} d\omega(t)=0 \ \ \ (n=1,2,3,...)$$
If we let $f(z)$ be the Fourier-Stieltjes transform of $\omega(t)$, i.e., if
$$f(z)=\int_a^b e^{iz t} d\omega(t)$$
then $f(z)$ is an entire function, not identically zero, and $f(z)$ vanishes at every $\lambda_n$.

**Question**. For the same reasons, and for the same Riesz representation theorem, can we conclude that
$$f(z)=\int_a^b \operatorname{sinc}(z-t) d\omega(t)$$
is an entire function, not identically zero, that vanishes at every $\lambda_n$?

Comment: Do you mean: If the subspace generated by functions $\phi_{n}(z)=\mbox{sinc}(z-\lambda_{n})$ is not dense in $C[a,b]$, then you end up with an entire function $f$ that is not identically $0$ which vanishes at every $\lambda_{n}$?

Comment: Yes, of course...

Comment: What you have to be able to show is this: If $\mathcal{S}$ is the closed linear subspace of $C[a,b]$ spanned by $\{ \mbox{sin}(\lambda_{n}-t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, and if $S \ne C[a,b]$, then there exists $z$ such that $s_{z}(t)=\mbox{sin}(z-t)$ is not in $S$. Do you have a reason to believe that is true?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote $\sin$ in the last comment instead of $\mbox{sinc}$.

Comment: Then $f(z)=\int_a^b \operatorname{sinc}(z-t) d\omega(t)$ isn't an entire function?

Comment: The function $f$ is an entire function. The issue is the whether or not the property I stated for the subspace $\mathcal{S}$ holds.